# jdbc microsoft sql driver didn't works

Tags: jdbc

I am studying Accessing Databases with JDBC. I made a database in Microsoft Sql express 2012 and i wrote the java code in Eclipse IDE then i downloaded the jdbc sql driver but my project didn't run. I added the external jar file to my project but it didn't works for me. Here is the java code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DisplayAuthors {



    static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Books;";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection( DATABASE_URL );

            statement = connection.createStatement();

            resultSet = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT AuthorID, FirstName, LastName FROM Authors" );

            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
            System.out.println( "Authors Table of Book Database:\n" );

            for ( int i = 1; i < numberOfColumns; i++ ) 
                System.out.printf( "%-8s\t", metaData.getColumnName( i ) );
            System.out.println();

            while ( resultSet.next() ) {
                for ( int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++ ) 
                    System.out.printf( "%-8s\t", resultSet.getObject( i ) );
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        catch ( SQLException exception ) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
                statement.close();
                connection.close();
            }

            catch ( Exception exception ) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get errors: if so: please post the stacktrace

Comment: No suitable drivers found for jdbc. This is the error message @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Then the driver isn't on the classpath, or you are using a very old (pre JDBC 4) driver without explicitly loading the driver.